# If a person has faith in his heart but he/she utters words of kufr both intentionally or unintentionally does that person become a kafir?

Tags: kufr

**If a person has faith in his heart but he/she utters words of kufr both intentionally or unintentionally does that person become a kafir ?**

I want to know if a person utters words of kufr intentionally or unintentionally does that person become a kafir and he/ she has to enter islam again by reciting the shahadah again.

I have so much waswas that whenever I talk I think I uttered words of kufr and I say the shahadah again and again. This is making me so worried that may be I am doomed to hell because I uttered words of kufr and don't know what to do.

**Some example below of my situation:** 
By words of kufr I mean any statement that makes a person leave islam. For example when I say Shahadah I say there is no one who is worthy of worship except Allah and that Muhammad S.A.W is the last and final messenger of Allah.(English translation of the Shahdah in Arabic). But when I say Muhammad (S.A.W) I have waswas who is God and it seems like naozobillah as if I said God to Muhammad . This is making me sick now. Even when I talk I use simple words like 'is' 'me' etc and then waswas comes who is God and it feels like if I said God to someone else or myself respectively.

Comment: Please elaborate: what do you mean by word of kufr...

Comment: @Medi1Saif If you can please answer my question regarding this I'll be thankful because I am too stressed and I am thinking may be I am going to hell forever and I am doomed. I don't know what to do. I am thinking too much and it is leading me to this grave sin of kufr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

- Uttering words of Kufr intentionally makes someone a Kafir/disbeliever. (Words uttered under duress/compulsion or during insanity or such situations are excused).
- On the other hand, uttering words of Kufr unintentionally e.g., out of ignorance or a mere slip of the tongue does not make the person a Kafir. But that person is required to repent upon realization of their words.

What you are describing as happening to you does not fall into either of the above categories.

You are just getting Waswasa (whispers of Satan). These are **thoughts**, not actual words spoken.

> Abu Hurairah said; His companion came to him and said; Messenger of Allah! We have thoughts which we cannot dare talk about and we do not like that we have them or talk about them. He said:
>   Have you experienced that? They replied: yes. He said : that is clear faith.

Above narration is found in [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/339) and similar is found in [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/247).

You haven't done anything wrong. In fact, your disgust at those satanic whispers demonstrates your faith. Ignore those thoughts and continue with the worship of Allah, may He bless you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are suffering from severe waswas.
Try doing self ruqyah by @practical self ruqya by saeed abdullah on youtubw or search in google and you qill get to know how to do it.
You are suffering from severw waswas conditioning
Recite 4 qul
Surah Fatiha
InshaAllah you will be healed